# How to check if number is result of the sum of the binary?

Tags: c#, enums

I have situation like this:

got `enum`

```
enum MyType{
    None = 0,
    First = 1,
    Second = 2,
    Third = 4,
    //and so on 
}
```

now I wan't to check if given number is result of the sum of the binary for example

```
int givenNumber = 3;
int result = 
//how to get that it's sum of 2 enums in this particular case would be (int)Type.First & (int)Type.Second == 3;
```

Hope that my question is clear enough and someone can help with this.

**Edit**

1. enum values are always powered by 2
2. I want to write a method which should check that given number can be one pice of different binary sum example:`int givenNumber = 1; //1 , 3 ,5 and 7 will be the answer`
3. Real life sample:
   I got contractors in my db and every contractor can be Producer = 1,Supplier = 2,Service = 4 in db I can store only 1 value int in this case would be smartest choice. When I loading Items to my combobox of Service - Contractors I want load every row which have for example value 4 or 5 or 7 (beacuse 7 = 1+2+4, 5 = 1+4 and 4=4).

Is now my question more clear?

Comment: are your `enums` always power of 2?

Comment: Have a look at this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute

Comment: Do you mean sum, or bitwise and?

Comment: Nope, your question is not clear

Comment: try to add some more details about your question.

Comment: You're going to run into problems if you use reserved words in this way

Comment: @CHill60 it's only example I'm aware of `Type` is reserved

Comment: @harry180 That was my point - `Type` is an abstract class but you've used it as the name of your enum. If you look at the solutions you'll note that every one of them has used more appropriate name for the enum

Comment: @harry180 - Can you update your example so its a REAL example not one that A) Doesn't actually compile and B) is clear about if you want the SUM or bitwise AND?  Because a BITWISE AND WILL NOT result in what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the individual enums like this:

```
static IEnumerable<MyEnum> GetFlags(this MyEnum e)
{
    var flags = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>();
    foreach (var flag in flags)
        if ((flag & e) > 0) yield return flag;
}
```

then you can use it like this:

```
int givenNumber = 3;
var results = ((MyEnum)givenNumber).GetFlags();
```

Comment: Neat! I was also going to suggest GetValues but missed the point on foreach - I've (re)learned something today!

Answer (score 1):

```
private enum YourType
{
    None = 0,
    First = 1,
    Second = 2,
    Third = 4,
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int givenNumber = 3;
    YourType castedNumber = (YourType)givenNumber;

    if ((castedNumber & YourType.First) == YourType.First)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First");
    }

    if ((castedNumber & YourType.Second) == YourType.Second)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second");
    }

    if ((castedNumber & YourType.Third) == YourType.Third)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Third");
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

Do note that:

1. This won't work for `None` (0) value, so you have to manually check for 0 (as `(x & 0)` is always 0)
2. All values must be power of 2
3. You might want to add the `[Flag]` attribute so other developers will now the enum will works with bitwise operations

Answer (score 0):

```
    enum Flag
    {
        None = 0,
        First = 1,
        Second = 2,
        Third = 4,
        Fourth = 8
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int givenNumber = 3;
        List<Flag> flags = new List<Flag>();

        int number, result;
        do
        {
            int step = 0;
            do
            {
                number = (int)Math.Pow(2d, ++step);
            } while (number < givenNumber);
            result = (int)Math.Pow(2d, step - 1);
            flags.Add((Flag)result);
            givenNumber -= result;
        } while (givenNumber != 0);

        Debugger.Break();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[Flags]
enum MyType{
  None = 0,
  First = 1,
  Second = 2,
  Third = 4,
  //and so on 
}
```

Using Flags attribute means a simple toString will give you what you want for your dropdown

i.e.

```
MyType test = (MyType)6;
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());
```

would now print:

```
Second, Third
```

instead of 6